# How to speed up of pocessing of gzip file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

I need to create a list of uniq `values([0]-position, delimeter '|')` from file `gzip`, which weight `1.5 GB`.
But processing is more 2,5 hours, please help to speed up processing.

```
import gzip
import time

with gzip.open("gzipfilename.gz", "rb") as gz:
    uniqSub = []
    for i in enumerate(gz):
        sepValues = str(gz.readline()).split("|")
        if sepValues[0] not in uniqSub:
            uniqSub.append(sepValues[0])
    print(len(uniqSub))
```

Comment: MY PC has CPU core i5 7400 3.0 Ghz, 8Gb RAM, SSD 120 GB.

Comment: why not read all the data into a variable and then process.

Comment: when I'm tring to use gz.readlines instead of current gz.readline, I've got error about Memory Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import gzip
import time

with gzip.open("gzipfilename.gz", "rb") as gz:
    uniqSub = set()
    for line in gz:
        sep, _ = line.split(b'|', 1)
        uniqSub.add(sep)
    print(len(uniqSub))

    # If you need to print...
    for item in uniqSub:
        print(str(item, 'utf-8'))
```

This simplifies reading over lines, removes the `enumerate()` since you are not using it, splits a maximum of one times, since you are only using the first token, and uses a set to speed up the set membership test. It should be faster.

Comment: sep, rest = line.split("|", 1)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Oops, I forgot to cast to `str`. Fixed.

Comment: Ok, I've run your code, let's wait, how long it will process.

Comment: sep, _ = str(line).split("|", 1)  Can you explain "sep, _" ?

Comment: Assuming a `|` exists in the line, `split("|", 1)` will return a two item list: the substring before the first `|` and the substring after the first `|`. This unpacks those two values into variables. The `_` variable is a way of discarding or ignoring the second value. You could also do `sep = str(line).split("|", 1)[0]`.